# Why Consecutive Animations Intertwine Each Other?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I want to create animations for a reflex test app.
Targets I call, are buttons that users can click in 500ms to get a score point.
I want my targets to fade in (250ms) and fade out after (250ms).
But when I execute the code down below, all of the targets (Button) starts to fade in and out after some time.
I am assuming the code can not make targets invisible correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Initialization of animations:

```
     animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in_250ms);
     animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out_250ms);
```

Method: (tempeRand is for not choosing the last target.)

```
    private void hideTargs() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randTarget = rand.nextInt(12);

        Animation.AnimationListener animListener = new Animation.AnimationListener(){
            int randTargetIn = randTarget;

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                if (animation == animationFadeIn){
                    buttonArray[randTargetIn].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if (animation == animationFadeIn) {
                    buttonArray[randTargetIn].startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
                } else if (animation == animationFadeOut) {
                    buttonArray[randTargetIn].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    int temperRand = 0;
                    boolean isDifferentRandom = false;
                    while (!isDifferentRandom){
                        temperRand = rand.nextInt(12);
                        if (temperRand != randTargetIn)
                            isDifferentRandom = true;
                    }
                    randTargetIn = temperRand;
                    buttonArray[temperRand].startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
                }
            }
        };

        // Set listener to animation
        animationFadeIn.setAnimationListener(animListener);
        animationFadeOut.setAnimationListener(animListener);

        // Start fade-in animation
        buttonArray[randTarget].startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
    }
```

**fade_in_250ms.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fillAfter="true" >
    
        <alpha
            android:duration="250"
            android:fromAlpha="0.0"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
            android:toAlpha="1.0" />
    
    </set>
```

**fade_out_250ms.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:fillAfter="true" >
        
            <alpha
                android:duration="250"
                android:fromAlpha="1.0"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
                android:toAlpha="0.0" />
        
        </set>
```

It should be one target visible at a time. But result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EyHD.jpg).

Comment: So you want to fade in - out one button at a time by calling the `hideTargs` function once?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to do that with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone wants to use this method, here is the answer to the question:

This flickering and unwanted animation on multiple Views:

[image]

happens because we never stopped or cleared the animation for the last View. Now I added **.setAnimation(null)** to clear the animations.

Updated code:

```
private void hideTargs(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randTarget = rand.nextInt(12);

    Animation.AnimationListener animListener = new Animation.AnimationListener(){
        int randTargetIn = randTarget;

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            if (animation == animationFadeIn){
                buttonArray[randTargetIn].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if (animation == animationFadeIn) {
                buttonArray[randTargetIn].setAnimation(null);
                buttonArray[randTargetIn].startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
            } else if (animation == animationFadeOut) {
                buttonArray[randTargetIn].setAnimation(null);
                buttonArray[randTargetIn].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                int temperRand = 0;
                boolean isDifferentRandom = false;
                while (!isDifferentRandom){
                    temperRand = rand.nextInt(12);
                    if (temperRand != randTargetIn)
                        isDifferentRandom = true;
                }
                randTargetIn = temperRand;
                buttonArray[randTargetIn].startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
            }
        }
    };

    // Set listener to animation
    animationFadeIn.setAnimationListener(animListener);
    animationFadeOut.setAnimationListener(animListener);

    // Start fade-in animation
    buttonArray[randTarget].startAnimation(animationFadeIn);

}
```